# How to track or find 404 error in Woocommerce Admin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have one woo-commerce site in which when I open `Woocommerce->Orders` Its showing
`404 page not found error`, How Can I track what is the error?

Comment: Error log says anything?

Comment: no, nothing find in error_log nor wp_debug shows the error

Comment: put this in functions.php  error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Can you provide site access to check the issue?

Comment: @MujeebuRahman not working

Comment: @AhmedGinani sorry I can't

Comment: @developersaumya Either something will be in log or it should print in browser

Comment: @developersaumya Either something will be in log or it should print in browser

Comment: @MujeebuRahman no, nothing

Answer (score 2):

What setting have you got at
Admin page > WooCommerce > settings > Checkout tab, Checkout endpoints: Order received. Does it say “order-received”

Did you reset permalinks?
Admin page > Settings > Permalinks, then click “Save Changes” twice (even though there are no changes)

I’m interested to know if the other pages work (cart and checkout)

please changed the used theme and deactivated each plugin then reactivate one by one.

Comment: I am talking about admin Woocommerce->orders

Comment: I am talking about too, please deactivate your theme and use another one and check it is working or not. then check is their woocommerce.php file has been defined into your themes directory or not.